# Error in using accuracy_score from sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing planar data classification using logistic regression. An error is occured after importing accuracy score. Why didnt it work? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437893/how-to-calculate-logistic-regression-accuracy) suggested that accuracy score is used to estimate accuracy.The last line and third last line of code must give same answer. But third last line of code only gave actual answer(i.e 47% accurate LR). I also applied this code 
    score= accuracy_score(Y,LR_predictions)
But i got an error: too many indices

```
 import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from testCases_v2 import *
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.linear_model
from planar_utils import plot_decision_boundary, sigmoid, load_planar_dataset, load_extra_datasets
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X, Y = load_planar_dataset()

plt.scatter(X[0, :], X[1, :], c=Y, s=40, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral);

plot_decision_boundary(lambda x: clf.predict(x), X, Y)
plt.title("Logistic Regression")

# Print accuracy
LR_predictions = clf.predict(X.T)
print(LR_predictions)
print ('Accuracy of logistic regression: %d ' % float((np.dot(Y,LR_predictions) + np.dot(1-Y,1-LR_predictions))/float(Y.size)*100) +
       '% ' + "(percentage of correctly labelled datapoints)")
score= accuracy_score(Y,LR_predictions)
print(score)



ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0f3a55d2e963> in <module>()
      8 print ('Accuracy of logistic regression: %d ' % float((np.dot(Y,LR_predictions) + np.dot(1-Y,1-LR_predictions))/float(Y.size)*100) +
      9        '% ' + "(percentage of correctly labelled datapoints)")
---> 10 score= accuracy_score(Y,LR_predictions)
     11 print(score)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
    170 
    171     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 172     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    173     if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):
    174         differing_labels = count_nonzero(y_true - y_pred, axis=1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     70     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     71     """
---> 72     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     73     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     74     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    179     if len(uniques) > 1:
    180         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 181                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    182 
    183 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 400]
```

Comment: Is Y only 0 and 1 in your case?

Comment: Can you edit you example to use a dataset from sklearn and be complete and minimal? This way we can run the code and see what's going on, and not just read it.

Comment: Wait, does an error occur, or are you getting the wrong answer?

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin yes error occurs. y is only 0 or 1

Comment: Well, please edit your question to include the error; it is an essential part of the question. To learn more on how to ask a good question, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Shall i post screenshot

Comment: No, do not post a screenshot of code or errors. Copy the error itself, and put it in code formatting. I think this should be covered in "how to ask", please visit the link.

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215501/discussion-between-itamar-mushkin-and-auberron).

Comment: Make sure you're passing an array-like with one dimension to accuracy_score (for example, shape of (100,), not (1,100)).

Comment: We can fix by reshaping ?

Comment: Shall i post updated code just to know what is happening ?

Comment: Try for yourself if it fixes... it's worth a try

Comment: what are the shapes of Y and LR_predictions?

Answer (score 0):

Change the shape of Y to (n_samples,) that is required for accuracy_score method. Just try a code as follows:
Y = Y.reshape(1,-1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).